# Errors in glmer : Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : cannot find valid starting > values: please specify some

Tags: r, glm, lme4

I am trying to run a `glmer` model:

This is the model I am traying to run

```
md$count<-as.integer(md$count)
Model1 <- glmer (count ~ distance_nest_tag + ep_nest  + (1|tag_ID), 
              family = gaussian (link="log"),           
              data=md )
```

- `count` is an integer from 0 to 19 which indicates the number of visits.
- `distance_nest_tag` is a continuous variable in meters
- `ep_nest` is a binary variables ( 1, 0)

and the random effect terms are just numbers of nests and individuals.

I also have tried this

```
Model1 <- glmer (count ~ distance_nest_tag + ep_nest + (1|tag_ID), 
              family = gaussian (link="log"),
               start = coef (lm(md$count ~ md$distance_nest_tag + md$ep_nest)),                 
              data=md )
```

But I always get this

```
> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) :    cannot find valid starting
> values: please specify some
```

Any thoughts???

```
dput



       Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: EP0 ~ counts + dist_mean_hour + nest_reproductive_period + X.vistors +  
    (1 | nest_ID) + (1 | tag_ring_ID) + (1 | distance_nesttag_nest) +      (1 | date)
   Data: only_visits_encounternet
     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
 34.7643  81.1238  -7.3822  14.7643      752 
Random effects:
 Groups                Name        Std.Dev.
 date                  (Intercept)  8.507  
 distance_nesttag_nest (Intercept) 68.095  
 tag_ring_ID           (Intercept) 64.491  
 nest_ID               (Intercept)  2.251  
Number of obs: 762, groups:  date, 96; distance_nesttag_nest, 35; tag_ring_ID, 20; nest_ID, 19
Fixed Effects:
              (Intercept)                     counts             dist_mean_hour  
                -13.08952                   -1.80786                   -0.04528  
nest_reproductive_periodI  nest_reproductive_periodP                  X.vistors  
                 -4.04944                   -1.56264                    0.06601  
convergence code 0; 1 optimizer warnings; 0 lme4 warnings 
> dput(R)
structure(list(nest_ID = c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), nest_reproductive_period = structure(c(3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("F", "I", "P"), class = "factor"), 
    tag_ID = c(23L, 23L, 23L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L), ring_tag_id = structure(c(3L, 
    3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("AU34180", "AU70442", 
    "BD12273"), class = "factor"), age_tag = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, NA, NA), p3_tag = c(590L, 590L, 590L, 585L, 585L, 
    585L, 590L, 590L), weight_tag = c(1770L, 1770L, 1770L, 1843L, 
    1843L, 1843L, 1856L, 1856L), next_box_tag = c(42L, 42L, 42L, 
    56L, 56L, 56L, 0L, 0L), dist_mean = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA), count = c(3L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), comb = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("6_0", "6_42", "6_56"
    ), class = "factor"), distance_nest_tag = c(0.189813484, 
    0.189813484, 0.189813484, 0.649465717, 0.649465717, 0.649465717, 
    NA, NA), epp_male_comb = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
    ), epp_male = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), nest_epmale = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), neighbour = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), ep_nest = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), roost_nextbox_tag = c(8L, 8L, 8L, 335L, 335L, 335L, 
    332L, 332L), nestroost = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("6_332", "6_335", "6_8"), class = "factor"), 
    neighbours_roost = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("nest_ID", 
"nest_reproductive_period", "tag_ID", "ring_tag_id", "age_tag", 
"p3_tag", "weight_tag", "next_box_tag", "dist_mean", "count", 
"comb", "distance_nest_tag", "epp_male_comb", "epp_male", "nest_epmale", 
"neighbour", "ep_nest", "roost_nextbox_tag", "nestroost", "neighbours_roost"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

**Edit**

Here is small reproducible example of a dataset that contains 0 in the response variable and a grouping variable.

```
dat = structure(list(y = c(0, 13.0988072077744, 1.53920266020577, 12.1207857178524, 
33.9470080593601, 0, 0, 3.46572339150589, 1.05917038733605, 14.295924854232, 
11.2930736701237, 8.1866351980716, 0.0106620794860646, 0.731016675010324, 
5.99548577982932, 0, 0, 3.15404516097624, 7.62275500199758, 0.604545763926581, 
0, 2.37143378704786, 2.39386320579797, 0.800569675164297), x = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.43684896701947, 0.808418724797666, 0.672910050840583, 
0, 0.763154948372394, 1.44573423753027, 0.96113385074772, 0, 
0.498556550480425, 2.43977373047965, 1.55665618954226, 0.88557694968069, 
4.12758995011915, 3.16827587767271, 2.55354765986558, 3.99502024875255, 
1.71053826174466, 3.59887218330055), tag = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5)), .Names = c("y", 
"x", "tag"), row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = "data.frame")

mod2 = glmer(y ~ x + (1|tag),
           data = dat, family = gaussian(link = log), 
           start = list(theta = 1, coef(lm(y ~ x, data = dat))))
```

Comment: does `count` have zero values in it?

Comment: Yes, it goes from 0...

Comment: Please provide data to make this a reproducible example. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  Thank you for the update you just made but the data should be in a reproducible format such as `dput` to make it easily imported in our R sessions to help us help you.

Comment: Sorry Hack-R done!

Comment: also, presumably, this isn't *all* of your data - it would really be most useful to have all of it (you may need to post a link to the data rather than dumping it all on this page)

Comment: Yea, I didn't want to say anything but the issue is specific to your data and this is so little data we can't reproduce the error. I was trying to simulate it, but more rows would really help. You can use `dput` to make it easier on us. Mr. Bolker can correct me if I'm wrong, but I think even 150 - 200 rows would most likely be enough. You can put the `dput` on http://www.pastebin.com and give us the link.

Comment: Anyway, I think the problem is just using the 0's with the log link right? @BenBolker can't she just add a small peturbation to make it work? Like `.Machine$double.eps`?

Comment: busy right now ... need to get back to this a little later

Comment: OKay I will.. thanks I was trying to put it here but did not work, I am going to do it assap, thanks

Comment: http://pastebin.com/k0y5CSAu

Comment: Thank you both for all! I have read when looking for the solution  that the zeros can be the problem, but not really sure how to do this peturbation..

Comment: Model1 <- glmer (visitors ~ distance_nest_tag + ep_nest + (1|tag_ID), 
              family = gaussian (link="log"),
               start = coef (lm(md$count ~ md$distance_nest_tag + md$ep_nest)),                 
              data=md )

Comment: Model1 <- glm (md$ visitors ( y+.Machine$double.eps)~ md$distance_nest_tag + md$ep_nest + (1| nest_ID) + (1|tag_ID), 
          family = gaussian (link="log"),
          data=md )

Comment: I am now trying this code                Model1 <- glm ( I ( visitors + .Machine$double.eps)~ distance_nest_tag + ep_nest + (1| nest_ID) + (1|tag_ID), 
          family = gaussian (link="log"),
          data=md )
But is also not working I get now the following error :                                                                                                                                             Error: no valid set of coefficients has been found: please supply starting values

Comment: your pastebin looks incomplete: it starts "151L, 151L,... " ???

Comment: [This answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/61496/29350) on cross validated discusses a quite similar issue in package mgcv.  In that case the issue could be traced back to a bug.

Answer (score 4):

**tl;dr** To make this work you need to set the `mustart` parameter to something sensible; a similar issue with `mgcv` is reported [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61480/gam-log-link-does-not-work-without-starting-values/61496#61496). In current versions of `glmer` , you would just need to include

```
mustart=pmax(dd$count,1e-3)
```

in the `glmer` call.

The explanation: the iterative algorithm typically used in GLMs (iteratively reweighted least squares) needs to set a starting point, not just for the parameters, but also for the predicted response values. The default for Gaussian models is to set the predicted values equal to the observed; if the observed value is an impossible *predicted* (mean) value for the particular link function (e.g., a zero value becomes negative-infinite when log-transformed), then this will break stuff (even if the observed value is legal (i.e., we can observe a zero value even when the mean is constrained to be positive). Therefore, the `$initialize` component of a `gaussian(link="log")` family item is:

```
if (is.null(etastart) && is.null(start) && is.null(mustart) && 
    ((family$link == "inverse" && any(y == 0)) || (family$link == 
        "log" && any(y <= 0)))) 
    stop("cannot find valid starting values: please specify some")
mustart <- y
```

So what we really want to do is set `mustart` so all of the values are positive.

Then there's the question of whether this is the right statistical approach.  It's not insane; it might also be reasonable to try a Poisson model, or a simple linear model based on `log(1+x)`, or an ordinal model ... depending on what you think about the process driving the visits and on what you observe about the distribution/conditional distribution of the counts ...